# RNN with simultaneous POS tagging and sentiment classification?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on a problem where I need to perform simultaneous part-of-speech (POS) tagging and sentiment analysis. I'm using Tensorflow and am considering Keras.

I have a large data set of English sentences that have been labelled with both POS tags and with sentiment (negative, neutral, positive).

Is it possible to train a recurrent neural network (vanilla RNN, GRU, or LSTM) to learn **both** POS tagging and sentiment classification? Of course, during test time, I'd like to enter a sentence and have the RNN generate predictions for both the POS tags and the sentiment together.

I was thinking of the following RNN architecture. I'm not sure if it's possible with Tensorflow (which I've been using) or with Keras (which I'm just learning now). I've previously implemented RNNs that do one task, not two.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A really simple Keras model that might work for POS-tagging might look like this:

```py
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from keras.models import Model, Sequential


model = Sequential()
model.add(
    LSTM(
        hidden_layer_size,
        return_sequences=True,
        input_shape=(seq_length, nb_words),
        unroll=True
    )
)
model.add(Dense(nb_pos_types, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop")
```

Where I assume various parameters:

- `hidden_layer_size`: whatever dimension of the internal recurrent layer.
- `seq_length`: the input sequence length.
- `nb_words`: vocabulary size, for the one-hot encoded inputs detailing which word for which sequence position.
- `nb_pos_types`: number of different possible POS labels (for the one-hot encoded labels).

The goal is to modify a simple network like this so that it also makes a prediction about sentiment (not clear if your sentiment is a score or a category label, but I will assume a category label), and so that the loss function includes a penalty term for that sentiment prediction.

There are many ways to do this, but one common way is to "fork" a new spoke of the model off of some early layer, and have this spoke produce the additional prediction (often referred to as "multi-task" or "joint-task" learning).

To do this, we'll start off the same with `Sequential`, but rename it as `base_model` to make it clear that it serves as a base set of layers before branching for multiple tasks. Then we'll use Keras's functional syntax to do what we need with each branch before combining them together as multiple outputs of a `final_model`, in which we can express part of the overall loss function for each output.

Here's how we could modify the above example to do it:

```py
base_model = Sequential()
base_model.add(
    LSTM(
        hidden_layer_size,
        return_sequences=True,
        input_shape=(seq_length, nb_words),
        unroll=True
    )
)

# Get a handle to the output of the recurrent layer.
rec_output = base_model.outputs[0]

# Create a layer representing the POS prediction.
pos_spoke = Dense(nb_pos_types, activation="softmax", 
                  name="pos")(rec_output)

# Create a layer representing the sentiment prediction.
# I assume `nb_sentiments` is the number of sentiment categories.
sentiment_spoke = Dense(nb_sentiments, activation="softmax", 
                        name="sentiment")(rec_output)

# Reunify into a single model which takes the same inputs as
# determined for `base_model`, and provides a list of 2 outputs,
# one for each spoke (POS and sentiment).
final_model = Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, 
                    outputs=[pos_spoke, sentiment_spoke])

# Finally, use a dictionary for the loss function to specify the
# loss for each output, and optionally separate weights for when
# the losses are added as a weighted sum for the total loss.    
final_model.compile(
    optimizer='rmsprop',
    loss={'pos': 'categorical_crossentropy', 
          'sentiment': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
    loss_weights={'pos': 1.0, 'sentiment': 1.0}
)
```

And finally when calling `final_model.fit`, you'll supply a list for the labels, containing two tensors or arrays of labels, associated with each output.

You can read more about multi-output losses and architectures [at the Keras docs on multi-input and multi-output models](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models).

Finally, note that this is an exceedingly simple model (and would likely not perform well-- it's only meant for illustration). You could use the spokes we created, `pos_spoke` and `sentiment_spoke` to have additional layers with more sophisticated network topologies if you have particular POS-specific or sentiment-specific architectures.

Instead of defining them straight away as `Dense`, they could be additional recurrent layers, perhaps even convolutional, etc., followed by some eventual `Dense` layer whose variable name and layer name would be used for the appropriate places in the outputs and losses.

Also be aware of the use of `return_sequences=True` here. This allows for POS *and* sentiment prediction *at each step in the sequence*, even though you likely would only care about sentiment prediction at the end. One likely option would be to modify `sentiment_spoke` to operate only on the final sequence element from `rec_output`, or another (less likely) option would be to repeat the sentence's overall sentiment label for every word in the input sequence.

Comment: you won't find a lot of better answers for this

Comment: Thank you. In case anyone else is interested, the appropriate terminology for my problem is "multi-task learning". However, there aren't many resources or Stackoverflow answers for solving multi-task learning with Keras.